# Python 3.5.2 web-scraping - list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new web scraping and trying to scrape all the contents of Restaurant's Details Form so that I can proceed my further scraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = "https://www.foodpanda.in/restaurants"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("Section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")[0])
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i am getting IndexError: list index out of range
as error

Comment: Post your full explanation of the problem with a traceback. And if you got that error, it means that `soup.find_all("Section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")` is an empty list.

Comment: Could you post the entire error message?  I suspect the problem is in the findall(...)[0] statement.  If findall returns an empty list, then your call to index 0 is out of range.

Comment: trying get all the contents of Resturant Form and i am having error as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aenis\Desktop\zomotaScript.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(soup.find_all("Section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 6.2s]

Comment: Looks like `soup.find_all("Section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")` isn't return what you expect, what is that returning?

Comment: nothing. giving error as mentioned above

Comment: thanks # vishes_shell. as you said its returning empty list. so make modification as **bold** 'print(soup.find_all("article",class_="vendor list js-vendor-list-vendor-panel")[0])
' and got desired output.thanks bro

Comment: Please update the question to include your clarifications.  Also, would someone (@vishes_shell) please write up the answer for the OP to accept?  This will properly retire the issue.

Comment: @Prune, the answer is not in the comments, the problem is in the tag name, there is no such tag Section, all html tags are lowercase even if they were written in uppercase in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with accessing element at index `0` for `soup.find_all("Section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here"‌​)`, because the result is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

html has no notion of uppercase tag and regardless even in the source itself it is *section* not *Section* with a lowercase s:

```
section = soup.find_all("section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")[0]
```

Since there is only one you can also use find:

```
 section = soup.find("section",class_="js-infscroll-load-more-here")
```

Both of which will find what you are looking for.